# Expose directive methods to $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having some trouble with one of my Form directives :/ I want a directive that can communicate with others directives that i have in a page, and this directive would communicate with the controller. 
This directive are goint to expose some functionalities to work with the Form.

```
function Form() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        require: 'form',
        transclude: false,
        controller: ['$scope','$element','$attrs','$timeout', function($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
            let ctrl = this;

            $scope.obj = {}
            $scope.obj.fun1 = fun1;
            $scope.obj.fun2 = fun2;
            $scope.obj.fun3 = fun3;
            $scope.obj.fun4 =fun4;


            function fun1 (par1, par2){
                // code
            }

            function fun2(){
                // code
            }

            function fun3 (par1, par2, par3, par4){
                // code
            }

            function fun4(){
                // code
            }

        }]
    }
}
```

But, when i try to call one of those methods i exposed on the $scope, i get `undefined`. If i surround the method with a $timeout with no seconds set, for example, it works just fine. Is there a way to make this work without a $timeout?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what do these functions do and how are you using them?

Comment: they're working with the FormController and manipulating error messages of the form and its inputs

Answer (score 0):

Put those functions in a service, and inject them wherever you need them

Comment: Since those functions work with HTML too, i don't want to put those in a Service.

Comment: in that case you can use a wrapper in your directive that call the service function

Comment: it doesn't matter, since i can't call the directive's function from controller.